# Is it mandatory to Write static void Main(string[] args) in C#?

Tags: c#

Because I just debug a very simple program which took runtime inputs as two numbers and showed the sum of those two number. I did that without writing the string[] args. So is it really necessary to write these in every program?

Comment: I suggest you learn to read the language docs to answer such questions. It's far easier that way.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not mandatory.

The documentation on [Main() and Command-Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) clearly says:

> The Main method can be declared with or ***without*** a string[] parameter that contains command-line arguments.

So, this is also a valid entry point:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Main method is the entry point of a C# console application or windows application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.). When the application is started, the Main method is the first method that is invoked.
There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have more than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as the entry point. For more information, see /main (C# Compiler Options).**

1. The Main method is the entry point of an .exe program; it is where the program control starts and ends.
2. Main is declared inside a class or struct. Main must be static and it should not be public. (In the earlier example, it receives the default access of private.) The enclosing class or struct is not required to be static.

Answer (score 0):

The string[] args part is for cases when you want to support command line switches

```
myprogram.exe argument1 argument2
```

If you've got no plan to use them, you don't need the args.

Answer (score 0):

Public means, that a method is visible from outside. This makes sense, because you want that the loader will start this method from outside. But of course: technically it might have been possible to give it any other rights. But you have to see, that you can now even load the assembly and start this method yourself which might be important in some cases.

Static means, that the function can be called without having an instance of the class first. This makes a lot of sense because Main is the entry point and you want this function to be called without having an instance of the class first.
If you want to use arguments list while calling your application from the command line, than the C# language provides a string[] array called args that is populated with the command-line arguments from the Windows operating system. So for example you execute your application want to pass some argument to your application for further processing in the code you call you app like this from the command line:

"C:\ConsoleApplication1.exe a b c"

The value a b c will be stored in the args string array and can be accessed like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
{
string argument = args[i];
Console.Write(argument); // Write string
}
```

Also You may try this Article : http://www.dotnetperls.com/main